# Memory overflowed when performing a left join (lj)

Tags: left-join, dolphindb

```
for (num in getPeriod()){
  // iterate through columns
  for(col in getCol()){
    // factor calculation
    col_data = sql(select=[sqlCol("symbol"),sqlCol("trade_date"),sqlColAlias(makeUnifiedCall(funcByName("ema"),[sqlCol(col),num]),col+'_'+'ema_'+num)],from=data_table,groupBy=sqlCol(`symbol),groupFlag=0).eval()
    // keep two decimal places
    col_date[col+'_'+'ema_'+num]= col_data[col+'_'+'ema_'+num].round(2)
    result_base = select * from lj(result_base,col_data,`symbol`trade_date)
  }
}
```

As shown, I used the `lj` operation to join the `col_data` table to the `result_base` table. However, the data volume within the result table surged, leading to a memory overflow error.

How do I address this?

Comment: [ask] [mre] [Help]

Comment: It seems like you're grouping on symbol in `col_data` but joining on trade date in `result_base`? If trade date is not unique, you will rapidly get cross joins and your result will be enormous. I suggest you limit to two iterations then inspect your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether there are too many matching records in the right table corresponding to a specific key.

`lj` may return more rows than the left table, as it returns all the matching records from the right table. To return the same number of rows as the left table, consider using the `lsj`  operation.